# jQuery validation in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, validation

Hi, in my application I designed one admission like school. In that I am checking the validation. If I am checking the validation, it shows message correctly after I entered correctly then also it showing same error. What mistake did I do? Can anyone please tell me?

HTML code:

```
 <html>
  <head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_register.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/responsive.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation_script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

 <div>
    <label class="desc" id="age" >Age</label>
    <div>
      <input id="age" name="age" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="3" tabindex="1">
      <span class="val_age"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Validation code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var validation_holder;

    $("form#register_form input[name='submit_registration']").click(function() {

    var validation_holder = 0;
var age             = $("form#register_form input[name='age']").val(); 
        var age_regex       =      /^[0-9]{10,1000}$/; 
if(age == "") {
            $("span.val_age").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!age_regex.test(age)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_age").html("Invalid Age!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_age").html("");
            }
        }   
if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 

}); // jQuery End
```

I am checking validation by using jQuery plugin.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are setting html to tags using the jquery function. So even if you have entered correct details, it will show up the text. So you need to empty it at first like:

```
$("form#register_form input[name='submit_registration']").click(function() {

$("span.val_age").html("");             // empty the span html
// your code starts here
}
```

CODE:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var validation_holder;
 $("span.val_age").html(" "); 
    $("form#register_form input[name='submit_registration']").click(function() {
 $("span.val_age").html(" "); 
    var validation_holder = 0;
var age             = $("form#register_form input[name='age']").val(); 
        var age_regex       =      /^[0-9]{10,1000}$/; 
if(age == "") {
            $("span.val_age").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!age_regex.test(age)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_age").html("Invalid Age!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_age").html("");
            }
        }   
if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 

}); // jQuery End
```

Comment: where i have to use this one

Comment: This should be the first lines in the function where you are submitting the data.ie, `$("form#register_form input[name='submit_registration']").click(function()`

Comment: Hi y u wrote 2times $("span.val_age").html(""); this line

Comment: var age = $("span.val_age").html(""); like this i used then also not working

Comment: Replace your code with the code I have added in my answer and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Hi then also same message is showing i entered correctly also

Comment: can you please tell me what i did mistake in regex

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52376/discussion-between-jenz-and-user3437313)

Answer (score 0):

You have specified Age field size as 3 but in validation ie                                    var age_regex =/^[0-9]{10,1000}$/;                                                              10,000 means length.replace 10,000 by 3 so length can be upto 3 numbers.

Comment: i used same var age_regex =/^[0-9]{10,1000}$/; like thisits not working

Comment: replace by var age_regex =/^[0-9]{3}$/;

Answer (score 0):

A more clean solution for validation [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HnrGY/212/) use if you like it, you can update your regex depending on your requirement.

```
$("#frm").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        age: { required: true, regex:/^(\d{2})$/ }
    },
    messages: {
        age: { required:"required", regex: "only two digits allowed for age"}
    }
});
```